# Getter Method is returning two different objects identityHashCodes

Tags: java, multithreading, return, objectid

helping a friend on a project we tried to debug a problem and then encountered an even more puzzling problem. I have a thread get the value of a certain variable via a getter method and print its identityHashCode every 500ms. All works fine until the variable is changed within the Game class. Then the returned identityHashCode starts to jump fore and back between the new and the old object. Thats a behavior I have never seen before and hoped you guys had any advice or even hint on whats happening.

Thanks in advance, I attach part of the source code and the console output.

```
public GamePlayState(int sid) {
            stateID = sid;
            entityManager = StateBasedEntityManager.getInstance();
            game = new Game(this);
            //TEST CODE ONLY
            Thread t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
    }

    /******TEST CODE ONLY******/
    public synchronized void run () {
            while (true) {
                    System.err.println(System.identityHashCode(game.getShootL()));
                    try {
                            wait(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
    }
```

Output

> 611581887
>   611581887
>   611581887
>   611581887
>   611581887
>   611581887
>   *Now value is changed*
>   1709366259
>   611581887
>   1709366259
>   611581887
>   1709366259
>   611581887
>   1709366259

Comment: Note that it's going to be difficult to help you without an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Remember that fields accessed from multiple threads should be marked as volatile or manually synchronized.

Comment: So much badness....what exactly do you mean by Object ID

Comment: Sorry for that rather bad wording I mean the identityHashCode of the returned boolean object

Answer (score 0):

We were unable to find a real answer so far but making the variable returned by the getter Method static eliminated the problem. Looks like the underlaying 3rd party engine is messing with the objects variables!?